# Loop through Xmltype in stored proc

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to parse/loop through simple xml to capture a single value and in the future do something with it.

This code works... sort of - see in-code comments

```
Declare 
    /* 2-item xml */
    x nvarchar2(1000) := '<values><value>1,"rrr|</value><value>2</value></values>';
    xt XmlType;
    /* expect c = 2 in the end */
    c number := 0;
Begin
   xt := XmlType.CreateXML(x);

   for rec in (SELECT extractvalue(value(xTbl), '/values/value/text()') val FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(xt, '//values/value'))) xTbl)
   loop
       /* This obviously runs two times but prints nothing */
       dbms_output.put_line(rec.val); 
       /* this works well */
       c := c + 1;
   end loop;
   /* This works correctly */
   dbms_output.put_line('Count: ' || c); 
End;
```

As you see, I get correct number of loops but there is nothing in `rec.val`. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXTRACTVALUE is deprecated. Instead, use [XMLTABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm#SQLRF06232).

```
SQL> SELECT xtbl.val 
FROM XMLTABLE('values/value'
        PASSING XMLTYPE('<values><value>1,"rrr|</value><value>2</value></values>')
        COLUMNS val VARCHAR2(10) PATH '.'
        ) xtbl;

VAL
----------
1,"rrr|
2
```

Use this query in your cursor.

```
declare 
    x nvarchar2(1000) := '<values><value>1,"rrr|</value><value>2</value></values>';
    xt XmlType;
    c number := 0;
Begin
   xt := XmlType.CreateXML(x);

   for rec in (
    SELECT xtbl.val 
        FROM XMLTABLE('values/value'
            PASSING xt
            COLUMNS val VARCHAR2(10) PATH '.'
            ) xtbl
            )
   loop
       dbms_output.put_line(rec.val); 
       c := c + 1;
   end loop;
   dbms_output.put_line('Count: ' || c); 
End;
/


1,"rrr|
2
Count: 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I accept your answer because it is more complete. Although @Shaun Peterson was correct as well. Interestingly, old way works faster - on 10K iterations this code runs 1.5 seconds faster in my original form vs. using `XMLTable`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi change you don't need the whole path in the extractvalue...

Change it to the below and it should work for you

```
for rec in (SELECT extractvalue(value(xTbl), '/value') val FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(xt, '//values/value'))) xTbl)
```

Hope it helps